# How to resolve Google Suggested Canonical tag Issue?

Tags: canonical-url

I don't know how to fix this issue. Why does Google suggest another page as canonical, as opposed to the one selected by us? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Canonical links only work if they are targetting the correct page(s).

- `/menu/cuisine/14/` points to `/menu/cuisine/14/` - CORRECT
- `/menu.php?cuisineid=14` points to `menu.php?cuisineid=14` - INCORRECT

So, the problem is `menu.php?cuisineid=14` not pointing to the correct page. To fix simply ensure your ?query-strings canonical the correct SEF URLS e.g `?cuisineid=14` should be using this:

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.burmesekitchen.in/menu/cuisine/14/" />`

I can see that you also have `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` therefore you're at no risk but if you wish to suppress the warnings in GSC then fix the canonicals as I have said.

Or alternatively, make your site inaccessible using these query strings and have them 301 redirect to the SEF URLS.

Comment: Thanks for the support, We will try this.